Is it possible to duplicate a query and disconnect it in Power Query of Power BI, so it does not refresh?
I was wondering if there is a way to duplicate a query  (make a snapshot) in Power BI (Source: SQL) and prevent that duplicate from refreshing. For example, I want Power BI to memorize the view of my table as of today because tomorrow after automatic refresh it will change. Suppose, you are working with a worksheet in Excel, which has tons of formulas, and you manually copy and paste the data as values to a separate sheet -- it will stay there forever unchanged because formulas were broken. I am trying to find an equivalent in Power BI/ Power Query. Thanks!
I tried Duplicate and Reference features but they are not that.

Power BI is not a database and is not suited to storing the history of your data. You can duplicate and import your data and turn of the refresh if needed

Unchecking "Include in Report Refresh" on the query will disable the refresh of the duplicate query. Here is more info.
